# Multiple perfect rings/circle in css3

Tags: html, css

I want to recreate this logo with CSS3. The rings of the logo all need to be individually click-able / intractable. How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: use circles and squares on different levels using z-index.

Comment: You need to show a substantial attempt before asking questions.

Comment: We can help you if you put your code in a fiddle. Your logo is doable with simple css rules.

Comment: not sure if it's possible with circles, squares and z-index, one circle will always be on to of another. http://jsfiddle.net/Yokocapolo/3ounyorf/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ut0yru75/)

The wrapper you can get rid of, it was only to help display it inside that little window.
The correct font you will have to find yourself.

LINK (not very accurate though)

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,200italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

CSS:

```
    .wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        margin: 40px;

        }           
        div {
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            background: #fff;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .four {
            height: 510px;
            width: 510px;
            border: 17px solid rgb(120,245,63);
            border-top-color: #fff;
            transform: rotate(-135deg);
            margin: -315px 0 0 -315px;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            }

        .three {
            height: 450px;
            width: 450px;
            border: 17px solid rgb(62,170,245);
            border-top-color: #fff;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            margin: -242px 0 0 -242px;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;    
            }
        .two {
            height: 370px;
            width: 370px;
            border: 17px solid rgb(238,31,122);
            border-top-color: #fff;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            margin: -202px 0 0 -202px;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;  
            }
        .one {
            height: 240px;
            width: 240px;
            border: 17px solid rgb(255,147,30);
            border-top-color: #fff;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            margin: -137px 0 0 -137px;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            }

        .logo {
            height: 75px;
            width: 75px;
            margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            font-size: 72px;
            font-style: italic;
        }

    sup {
        font-size: 16px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 15px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="four" onclick="clickMe(this)">
        <div class="three" onclick="clickMe(this)">
            <div class="two" onclick="clickMe(this)">
                <div class="one" onclick="clickMe(this)">
                    <div class="logo">MG<sup>24</sup></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** 
Per @arifix's request.
To make the rings clickable individually, add this to your code and make sure to add an onClick event listener to your rings.

JavaScript:

```
    function clickMe(element)
    {
       if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

        // Do what you want with class
        elementClass = element.className;
        console.log(elementClass);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know, it takes a lot of time. Is it possible to make every single ring/circle click-able individually? Thanks agian.

Comment: How can i set href link of each ring?